# CouchDB-river and related documents

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

I have a product which is owned by a user in my CouchDB.

```
product =
  name: 'Laptop'
  userId: somelongid

user =
  username: 'James'
```

With views and include_docs=true it returns:

```
product =
  name: 'Laptop'

  user =
    username: 'James'
```

( I know it doesn't exactly return the above but it's close enough )

I do this cause every time I need a product I also need the owner (to link to his page). At first I thought I would just use include_document=true on the _change feed but of course that does something else.

So how can I get the related user when getting product results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to collect all the userIds from the search result and query the _all_docs view in couchDb to get the users.

Answer (score 0):

use a view (f.E. "userByDocId") that emits (doc._id,doc.user)
and do a query userByDocId?key="Username"